# How to show data labels on highchart bar consoletv/charts package for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, highcharts, charts

i need show data values on every bar of a highchart graph using consoletv/charts package

```
$chart = Charts::create('bar', 'highcharts')
            ->title('Tr' . html_entity_decode('á', ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8") . 'fico Diario')
            ->elementLabel('Tr' . html_entity_decode('á', ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8") . "fico")
            ->labels($dias)
            ->values($values)
            ->dimensions(585, 500)
            ->responsive(true);
```

I only see the xAxis and yAxis values, but into every bar I don't see his value

This is the result of this code...

[image: bar chart using consoletv charts and highchart type]

Comment: With javascript and highcharts library I saw thar I can do it by using plotOptions, but with this package I don't see any way.

Comment: Hi @Yoedusvany Hdez, That problem is not closely related with Highcharts - rather with `Laravel Charts`. You can enable `dataLabels` in Highcharts in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/afpjtgnm/